# call child method from parent without ref in VUE3

Tags: vue.js, components, ref

I'm trying to call child method from parent.

I use a library which actually does NOT support VUE 3.
It has VUE3 Beta version,that means it won't support VUE 3 perfectly.

the code is like this:

```html
<grid-layout
          
          ref='gridlayout'
          v-model:layout="layout"
          :col-num="6"
          :row-height="70"
          :is-draggable="draggable"
          :preventCollision='true'
          :verticalCompact="false"
          :isResizable="false"
          :use-css-transforms="true"
          :maxRows='5'
     >

          <!-- can not use ref here -->
          <grid-item
            :key="item.key" v-for="item in layout"
            :x="item.x"
            :y="item.y"
            :w="item.w"
            :h="item.h"
            :i='item.i'
          >
            <span class="text">{{item.i}}</span>
          </grid-item>
        </grid-layout>
```

It doesn't support ref on grid-item,but I need the function which is declared in it.

I tried:

```
__vueParentComponent.proxy
```

but it doesn't work under production mode.
is the only way I change the source code and open a request on GitHub?!
related questions are so hard to search. hope someone can help me...

edit:
sorry for incomplete question.
this is the library I use.
https://jbaysolutions.github.io/vue-grid-layout/

I want to dymanic grab a new grid-item into the grid-layout.
the library offer the way to grab from outside,but I face a problem that "$children" is removed in VUE 3.

https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout/blob/master/website/docs/.vuepress/components/Example10DragFromOutside.vue

there is the wrong code library offers:

```
// get the grid-item
let el = this.$refs.gridlayout.$children[index];

// call grid-item function to calculate the new position
let new_pos = el.calcXY(mouseXY.y - parentRect.top, mouseXY.x - parentRect.left);
```

I edited it to:

```
var gridlayout = ref()
let el = gridlayout.value.$refs.item.children[index]
let new_pos = el.__vueParentComponent.proxy.calcXY(mouseXY.y - parentRect.top, mouseXY.x - parentRect.left)
```

it doesn't work in production mode.
I get the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'proxy')
```

does there have ways to replace "$children" without ref?

Comment: A ref is needed any way. The question is incomplete. It is very specific to the library and cannot be asked in general.

Comment: With little detail to go on, maybe wrap the grid-item in a div that you can then reference?

Comment: sorry for incomplete question. I edited the question for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem just now, my solution is to get the subcomponent directly

```
<grid-item
          ref="gridItemRef"
          v-for="item in layoutData"
          :x="item.x"
          :y="item.y"
          :w="item.w"
          :h="item.h"
          :i="item.i"
          :key="item.i"
          @resized="resizeEvent"
        >
          {{ item.i }}
        </grid-item>

gridItemRef.value[layoutData.value.length].$el.style.display = "none";
const el = gridItemRef.value[index];
el.calcXY(
      mouseXY.y - parentRect.top,
      mouseXY.x - parentRect.left
    );
```